# How to replace value of data value with defined variable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

In javascript, I have such code:

```
var tags_ext = $('*[data-val="301"]').data('val');
```

Can I define a variable to replace the "301"? Like this:

```
var tags_php = "301";
var tags_ext = $('*[data-val=tags_php]').data('val');
```

As I want to get the pre-set tag values from php. More information you can go to http://jsfiddle.net/bJHM8/11/ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript concatenation :

```
var tags_php = "301";
var tags_ext = $('*[data-val='+tags_php+']').data('val');
```

Comment: but use it carefully - if the `tags_php` variable has unexpected characters in it your code will break (or worse)

Answer (score 1):

Can you write a function that generates the dynamic selector.

```
   var tags_php = "301"
   var tags_ext = $(getDynamicSelector(tags_php)).data('val');

    function getDynamicSelector(tags_php){
      return "*[data-val=" + tags_php + "]"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
var foo='bar'
$('*[data-val='+foo+']').data('val')
```